# Calculating Point on a Sphere

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spheres, spherical-trigonometry

Given a sphere, I am attempting to calculate the coordinates of a point on that sphere given some initial point, the radius of the sphere, and some arbitrary distance *d* the point will travel (along with the vector it is headed). This sphere is a planet and the problem is essentially getting the coordinate of point #2 after traveling some distance.

I've been reading up on [Spherical Trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry) but I'm having a hard time applying it here. I'm thinking applying Rodrigues' formula might be a solution..?

I do have the North Pole position if that's any help at all.

**CONTEXT**
Planet is a perfect sphere with radius *r*. The coordinates are in a Cartesian plane with the center of the planet being (0, 0, 0). The "height" of the object relative to the surface of the sphere should remain the same.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Do you need to solve a specific problem? Can you write the problem?

Comment: It's gaming related. I need to calculate the Cartesian coordinates of point B given point A's Cartesian coordinates and the vector being traveled. Point B is the end destination in Cartesian coordinates.

Real application is to rotate an object about the sphere that travels some small distance every frame. So I plan to make small steps along the sphere and calculate the new coordinate of this object and I need the Cartesian coordinates in order to render it properly

Comment: I assume that the equation of the sphere is well defined. The distance d on the surface of the sphere creates and arc which with the known radius will allow you to calculate the angel change and from here the changes in the x,y,z of the point.

Comment: First, you should add the context in your comment to the body of your question. Then, you should add the mathematical flavor: what is your coordinate system (origin in the center of the sphere, $z$-axis in direction of the north pole, equator in the $x,y$-plane?), the coordinates of your starting point ($x_1,y_1,z_1$?) and the direction of the movement (a vector $(v_x,v_y,v_z)$? you can choose other variable names, of course). Then, you *could* try to solve it with spherical trigonometry, but that's rather tedious. With vector algebra, it's simple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding Terminal Lat/Long with initial lat/long, distance and bearing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767784/finding-terminal-lat-long-with-initial-lat-long-distance-and-bearing)

Comment: @awkward As the OP said in a comment (not in the question itself, unfortunately), they work in *Cartesian* coordinates. Converting to spherical, solving it with spherical geometry and converting back to Cartesian is easily the most tedious way imaginable for solving this simple problem.

Comment: @Moti The issue is I don't know what that equation might be, but I do suspect radius of the planet is relevant. Which is a known factor here

Comment: @ProfessorVector Sorry, added the relevant changes to the actual post. Are you saying awkward's solution would be tedious due to having to change back and forth from Spherical coordinates to Cartesian?

Comment: Is the travel along an arc? Could you add a simple drawing for clarification?

Answer (score 1):

That's how I understand the problem in mathematical language: We have a sphere with radius $r$ and a Cartesian coordinate system with origin in the center of the sphere. Given is a point with coordinates $x_1,y_1,z_1$ on the sphere, that means $$x^2_1+y^2_1+z^2_1=r^2.$$ This point is to move for a distance $d$ on the sphere, starting in a direction given by a vector $\overrightarrow{v}=(v_x,v_y,v_z)$. Of course, it's crucial that this direction be tangential to the sphere (otherwise the point would take off into space, or bury into the ground), i.e. $$x_1v_x+y_1v_y+z_1v_z=0.$$ We'll assume that the length of this vector is one, i.e. $$v^2_x+v^2_y+v^2_z=1.$$ Then, the movement of the point is a rotation in the plane given by the origin, the point and the direction $\overrightarrow{v}$, the rotation angle defined by the arc, $$\alpha=\frac{d}r.$$ Since the normal vector $\overrightarrow{n}=(x_1/r,y_1/r,z_1/r)$ and $\overrightarrow{v}$ are orthogonal, this will transform $\overrightarrow{n}$ into $\cos\alpha\,\overrightarrow{n}+\sin\alpha\,\overrightarrow{v}$, so the new position is
$$r\,(\cos\alpha\,\overrightarrow{n}+\sin\alpha\,\overrightarrow{v})=(x_1\,\cos\alpha+r\,v_x\,\sin\alpha,y_1\,\cos\alpha+r\,v_y\,\sin\alpha,z_1\,\cos\alpha+r\,v_z\,\sin\alpha).$$ For a very small distance $d$, we have $\sin\alpha\approx\alpha=d/r$ and $\cos\alpha\approx1$, so this becomes just $(x_1+d\,v_x,y_1+d\,v_y,z_1+d\,v_z)$, as one would expect. If, instead, $d=\pi\,r$, i.e. we're travelling half the circumference, we have $\cos\pi=-1$ and $\sin\pi=0$, and the new position will be $(-x_1,-y_1,-z_1)$ irrespective of the direction $\overrightarrow{v}$.